# RSA decrypt incorrect parameter

Tags: c#, encryption, hash, cryptography, rsa

For our program we do some preprocessing to validate the integrity of some data files. We do this by calculating a hash encrypted with a private key and on runtime decrypt the hash using the public key and check it against the hash of the data files.

We have created a precompiler that automatically generates a new keypair. The public key gets put in a .cs-file somewhere and will be used by the program. The private key information is stored in a temporary file to be used later by a program that calculates the hash and encrypts it.

This is the code that generates the keypair and stores it.

```
// make keys
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(384);
var key = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

// store public key in generated cs file
File.WriteAllText(Program.keyFileName, string.Format(Program.keyFileTemplate, Convert.ToBase64String(key.Exponent), Convert.ToBase64String(key.Modulus)));

// store private key in temporary file
File.WriteAllText("private-key.temp", rsa.ToXmlString(true));
```

After this, the actual program is compiled and we run a postcompiler. The RSA parameters are imported again as follows:

```
// read private key
string keyXml = File.ReadAllText("private-key.temp");
File.Delete("private-key.temp");

var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(384);
rsa.FromXmlString(keyXml);
```

We then process the data files and calculate a hash which is then saved to a variable called `hashBytes` (a byte array). Because I want to use the private key pair, I now decrypt this string using RSA (because encryption would use the public key pair and that is not what we want here) with the previously created instance as follows:

```
    var toEncrypt = new byte[rsa.KeySize / 8];
    hashBytes.CopyTo(toEncrypt, 0);

    try
    {
        rsa.Decrypt(toEncrypt, false);
    }
    catch (CryptographicException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("whoops: " + e.Message);
    }
```

However, this results in a CryptographicException "The parameter is incorrect." After looking around I have not even found the exact meaning of this error, but I suggest there is something wrong with the RSA parameters, which is surprising because I would assume using the XML string would just work.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I have removed the fixed key size and now encrypt the hashBytes directly. It seems I understood it wrong that the key and plaintext do not have to be the same size. However, I now get a "Bad Data." exception instead of the incorrect parameter one. Encryption does not give any errors though.

Comment: The key length you're using (384 bits) is so small, that you might as well just store just the plaintext hash unprotected.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out as well. I seem to have misinterpreted a source so I thought the keylength and plaintext size had to be equal. Right now I let the CryptoServiceProvider determine a keylength by itself, so that is solved. Thanks anyway for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using the Sign methods provided by the `RSACryptoProvider` I did not know about. The last code block has become the following:

```
try
{
    var hashBytes = rsa.SignData(stream, new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider());

    File.WriteAllBytes(Program.modPath + "default.rf-modsignature", hashBytes);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    throw;
}
```